# How can I get syntaxic coloration for Master Pages in MonoDevelop?

Tags: master-pages, syntax-highlighting, monodevelop

I think the title speaks for it self...

I mean, I can edit my master page file, it compiles and all but all the text is black. It's ok when it comes to .aspx or .ascx file but not for master pages...

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

[File a bug](http://monodevelop.com/Developers#Reporting_Bugs) against MonoDevelop, and hopefully it will be fixed in the upcoming 2.4 release.